# how to remove element from html using javascript function by clicking on button

Tags: javascript, html

i am new in javascript i need to call a javascript function when click a button and delete a div element
below the button element i use

```
<button id="delete_row"  onclick="deleterow(event,div1)></button>
```

div1 is the id of the div element i want to remove

javascript function

```
function deleterow(event,id) {

event.preventDefault();

    var elem = document.getElementById(id);
  elem.remove();//it dosent remove anything

  }
```

this is not working and doesn't remove any thing

Comment: If `div1` is the ID, you need to put it in quotes: `deleterow(event,'div1')`

Answer (score 3):

Remove element by id

For argument on button onclick you need to add target id `deleterow('removeMe')` of element you want to remove

```js
function deleterow(x) {
    var el = document.getElementById(x);
    if (el) {
        el.remove(); // remove target element
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="removeMe">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum beatae amet aut nobis optio? Natus quos beatae dignissimos totam doloribus neque animi velit excepturi accusamus voluptates eligendi dolorum, recusandae fugit.
</div>

<button id="delete_row" onclick="deleterow('removeMe')">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Don't just post code. Explain what the problem was and how you fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

HTML is based off a hierarchical structure of parents and children. In order to remove an element, you must command its parent to dispose of it.

```js
function deleterow(event, id) {

    event.preventDefault();
    var elem = document.getElementById(id);
    elem.parentElement.removeChild(elem);

}
```

Thanks to @Barmar I now know that `.remove()` is fully valid and is the equivalent of what I did above. Your actual issue is the lack of quotations as noted below:

Also, you'll likely need to tell HTML that 'div1' is a string:

```html
<button id="delete_row" onclick="deleterow(event,'div1')"></button>
```

Comment: This is not true. You're thinking of `removeChild()`.

Comment: `element.remove() == element.parentElement.removeChild(element)`

Comment: @Barmar yes, woops

Comment: Unless you need to support Internet Explorer, `remove()` is fine.

Comment: @Barmar I actually wasn't aware of `remove` until now. Thanks!